# Joining two data.tables in r: removing overlap duplicates while keeping duplicates in each separate dataset

Tags: r, merge, data.table, rbind

There are many questions and answers about [joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) two datasets, but I'm having trouble finding a solution to my current problem. I'm using `data.table` here.

I have two datasets, *dtx* and *dty*, with toy examples provided:

```
library(data.table)

dtx <- 
  structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
                        "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", 
                        "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g"
  ), date = structure(c(939340800, 939340800, 949622400, 949622400, 
                        887414400, 887414400, 920332800, 920332800, 831686400, 831686400, 
                        831686400, 845078400, 845078400, 969062400, 969062400, 975369600, 
                        979689600, 979689600, 892598400, 892598400, 921801600, 921974400, 
                        968284800, 968284800, 968284800, 968284800, 927158400, 927158400, 
                        993081600, 993081600, 993081600, 993081600, 1057190400, 1057190400
  ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), code = c(1215, 
                                                              1220, 1320, 1320, 236, 300, 1245, 850, 1415, 1415, 1279, 230, 
                                                              230, 1115, 1215, 8749, 1212, 1212, 1112, 1112, 4561, 8145, 8145, 
                                                              1497, 1112, 1112, 258, 1112, 230, 240, 1112, 1445, 260, 1112), 
  dataset = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
              "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
              "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
              "x")), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
              ))

dty <-
  structure(list(ID = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
                        "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
                        "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g"), 
                 date = structure(c(1055203200, 1055203200, 1055635200, 1058918400, 
                                    1058918400, 1074211200, 974764800, 974764800, 974764800, 
                                    979516800, 979516800, 975369600, 983491200, 983491200, 984528000, 
                                    987984000, 979689600, 979689600, 992217600, 992217600, 994896000, 
                                    995068800, 999043200, 999043200, 968284800, 968284800, 968284800, 
                                    968284800, 993081600, 993081600, 993081600, 993081600, 1057190400
                 ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), code = c(1112, 
                                                                             890, 8125, 2369, 1485, 1112, 1645, 1645, 794, 236, 4578, 
                                                                             8749, 230, 1114, 690, 720, 1212, 1212, 1112, 1112, 2060, 
                                                                             310, 1415, 310, 8145, 1497, 1112, 1112, 230, 240, 1112, 1445, 
                                                                             1112), dataset = c("y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
                                                                                                "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
                                                                                                "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
                                                                                                "y")), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                                                                                                ))
```

In each dataset, there is an *ID* that relates to a specific individual, a *date* for when an event occurs, a *code* for the type of event, and a dummy variable to indicate the *dataset* for each row (this is to keep track of which dataset a row comes from after joining).

An individual can have multiple rows representing multiple events across multiple dates. Further, an individual can experience multiple events on the same date, including multiple events of the same type (i.e., the same event code can appear more than once for an individual on a specific date).

I want to join these two datasets, where there are unique and shared rows between them. In joining them, I want to remove duplicate entries: where a specific *ID-date-code* combination appears in both datasets, I only want to keep the version from *dtx*. Further, I want to keep a record of which dataset the row is originally from, which is why I have the *dataset* dummy column

Here is the desired output:

```
dtresult <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                                  "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", 
                                  "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", 
                                  "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", 
                                  "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g"), date = structure(c(939340800, 
                                                                                              939340800, 949622400, 949622400, 1055203200, 1055203200, 1055635200, 
                                                                                              1058918400, 1058918400, 1074211200, 887414400, 887414400, 920332800, 
                                                                                              920332800, 974764800, 974764800, 974764800, 979516800, 979516800, 
                                                                                              831686400, 831686400, 831686400, 845078400, 845078400, 969062400, 
                                                                                              969062400, 975369600, 983491200, 983491200, 984528000, 987984000, 
                                                                                              979689600, 979689600, 992217600, 992217600, 994896000, 995068800, 
                                                                                              999043200, 999043200, 892598400, 892598400, 921801600, 921974400, 
                                                                                              968284800, 968284800, 968284800, 968284800, 927158400, 927158400, 
                                                                                              993081600, 993081600, 993081600, 993081600, 1057190400, 1057190400
                                  ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), code = c(1215, 
                                                                                              1220, 1320, 1320, 1112, 890, 8125, 2369, 1485, 1112, 236, 300, 
                                                                                              1245, 850, 1645, 1645, 794, 236, 4578, 1415, 1415, 1279, 230, 
                                                                                              230, 1115, 1215, 8749, 230, 1114, 690, 720, 1212, 1212, 1112, 
                                                                                              1112, 2060, 310, 1415, 310, 1112, 1112, 4561, 8145, 8145, 1497, 
                                                                                              1112, 1112, 258, 1112, 230, 240, 1112, 1445, 260, 1112), dataset = c("x", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "y", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "x", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "x", "x")), row.names = c(NA, -55L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "data.frame"))
```

I am having trouble joining the two datasets in this scenario, because an individual can have multiple of the same event type on a single date. This means I can't simply use `unique` or `duplicated` to identify the doubled up rows.

In my first attempt at joining the datasets I thought I would use `rbindlist`:

```
l = list(dtx, dty)
dtxy = rbindlist(l, use.names = TRUE)
dtxy = dtxy[order(ID, date, code, dataset)]
```

But then I realized I couldn't remove the overlapping rows without also taking out instances where an individual has multiple of the same event on one date.

Then I tried using `merge`:

```
dtxy = merge(dtx,
             dty,
             all = TRUE,
             by = c("ID", "date", "code"))
```

But this method doesn't deal with instances where the same event type occurs more than once on the same date and is duplicated across the two datasets!

I'm really struggling with this one - I also thought to use `funion`, but this is essentially the same as `merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `overlaps` coming from `y`:

```
l = list(dtx, dty)
dtxy = rbindlist(l, use.names = TRUE)

overlaps = merge(dtx,dty,by=c("ID","date","code"))[,.(ID,date,code,dataset = dataset.y)]

dtresultnew <- overlaps[dtxy,.(ID,date,code,x.dataset,i.dataset),on = .(ID,date,code,dataset)][
         is.na(x.dataset),.(ID,date,code,dataset=i.dataset)]

identical(dtresult[order(ID,date,code)],dtresultnew[order(ID,date,code)])
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty messy but,

```
a <-dtx %>%
  full_join(dty, by = c("ID", "date", "code")) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  distinct()
    #mutate(dataset = ifelse(!is.na(dataset.x), dataset.x, dataset.y))


b <- dtx %>%
  full_join(dty, by = c("ID", "date", "code")) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID, date, code) %>%
  filter(n()>1) %>%
  distinct()
c <- rbind(a,b) %>%
  mutate(dataset = ifelse(!is.na(dataset.x), dataset.x, dataset.y)) %>%
  select(-dataset.x, -dataset.y) %>%
  arrange(ID, date) 

sum(!(c %>% arrange(ID, date, code) == dtresult %>% arrange(ID, date, code)) )
[1] 0
```

`c` is what you wanted

```
> str(c)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  55 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ID     : chr  "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
 $ date   : POSIXct, format: "1999-10-08" "1999-10-08" "2000-02-04" "2000-02-04" ...
 $ code   : num  1215 1220 1320 1320 1112 ...
 $ dataset: chr  "x" "x" "x" "x" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: thanks this works, but is not `data.table`

Comment: @jmogil it's `data.table`

Comment: sorry, I should say that the functions you used to produce the solution were from `dplyr` and not in base r or `data.table` functions

Comment: @jmogil Oh...I didn't thought that this process had to use `data.table`...